# A list with n values in Python

Tags: python, list, user-input

I should get the following list as output:

`list1 = ['AB1', 'AB2', 'AB3', 'AB4', 'AB5', 'AB6', ..., 'ABn']`

The 'n' in the list is defined by the user. How can I create a list that contains these 'n' values. The output should look something like the following:

if `n = 15` (input from the user)

The list1 should be:

`['AB1', 'AB2', 'AB3', 'AB4', 'AB5', 'AB6', 'AB7', 'AB8', 'AB9', 'AB10', 'AB11', 'AB12', 'AB13', 'AB14', 'AB15']`

Note: this should work even if the 'n' is 10000. How do I do that?

Comment: `[f'AB{i}' for i in range(1,16)]` for `n=15`

Comment: @Epsi95 More specific just add n+1 at the place of 16 i.e `[f'AB{i}' for i in range(1,n+1)]` where n can be any integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
listOutput = [];
InputNumber = 15
for n in range(1, InputNumber+1):
    listOutput.append('AB'+ str(n))
print(listOutput)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You might want to read the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to find out about the conventions used in Python programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the variable created in a list comprehension as the input to an f-string

```
>>> n = 15
>>> [f"AB{x}" for x in range(1, n+1)]
['AB1', 'AB2', 'AB3', 'AB4', 'AB5', 'AB6', 'AB7', 'AB8', 'AB9', 'AB10', 'AB11', 'AB12', 'AB13', 'AB14', 'AB15']
```